# Super-CSV: how to do a "CSV Normalization"?

Tags: csv, normalization, supercsv

I would like to do a CSV normalization with the help of the Super-CSV-Dozer API.

I have a CSV file in the form of:

```
ObjectA_ID,ObjectA_Name,ObjectB_ID,ObjectB_Name
1,A_Name1,10,B_Name1
1,A_Name1,11,B_Name2
1,A_Name1,12,B_Name3
...
2,A_Name2,20,B_Name11
2,A_Name2,21,B_Name12
2,A_Name2,22,B_Name13
...
```

and after reading this file (for instance via `CsvDozerBeanReader`) I want to have a normalized representation of this data in the form of beans like:

```
Class ObjectA {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Collection objectBs;
    ...
}

Class ObjectB {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Is there a built-in possibility within Super-CSV-Dozer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each row represented a different `ObjectA` then I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504722/1068649) (I initially thought your question was similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369833/1068649)).

After reading your comments though, that's not going to help. The `ObjectA` columns are repeated for every `ObjectB` belonging to it.

Super CSV can't combine these for you, so you'll need to store each `ObjectA` in a map, e.g.

- For each a row read as an `ObjectA` bean (using CsvDozerBeanMapper)

  - Check if there's an `ObjectA` in the Map for the id

    - If yes, then update it by adding the current `ObjectB` to it
    - If no, then just add it to the Map
- Return the Map's values (the normalized `ObjectA`'s).

The downside to having to normalize is that you have to store every `ObjectA` in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I red your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504722/1068649) but as far as I understand it it does not solve my problem.

Comment: My question is for normalization of CSV-rows, not columns. So the question is, whether the Super-CSV/Dozer functionality can help out of the box to eliminate duplicates and do a "row-based" normalization of one "super-table" (the CVS-File) to several normalizes tables (the resulting Beans).

In you answer and in the samples the collection of dependent Beans (collection of answers) is originally modeled as set of columns within the csv file. But in my case there are several rows in the csv file, where for instance the data of ObjectA stays the same and the data of assigned ObjectB changes.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Thats just what I wanted to know: whether I have to do it on my own or with some help from supercsv/dozer.