# how to read .csv file as key value pair?

Tags: java, selenium, web, driver

```
username 1  abc
password 1  123
username 2  pqr
password 2  456
username 3  xyz
password 3  789
```

how to read `.csv file` values like `.properties file`, means whenever we give key name its should display value correspondence to that key in selenium?

when I enter `username1 it should display abc`. similarly,s for password1 it should display 123 in java

Comment: Please share the code you have worked on. Also, a simple google search would give you a lot of solutions.

Comment: key value pair is exactly a pair. What I see in ur example is a 3 column data. You cannot give username1, as username and 1 are different. Please edit your question properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCSV CSV to JavaBean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165421/opencsv-csv-to-javabean)

Comment: you can use OpenCSV utility to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your CSV file is structured as ->

```
username 1, abc
password 1, 123
username 2, pqr
password 2, 456
username 3, xyz
password 3, 789
```

Use the following ->

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.csv")));
String str="";
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
{
         map.put(str.split(",")[0],str.split(",")[1]);
}
```

This should give you the output.

Comment: suppose i am calling one method by name public void login (username1,password1)  , then the code should automatically take the values of username 1 and password 1 that is stored in .csv file and execute the remaining code

Comment: You can use get function of map to retrieve the values of your parameters passed in login function.